How to do not null check for columns in scala dataframe in an effective way?
I have a dataframe. I want to raise an exception if any of the column is having null. I can do it by hard coding column names and putting or conditions to check. How can i make it dynamic and performance effective.

There are several approaches to accomplish this task, and the following is one solution using the RAISE_ERROR function.
df.show(false)
+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|1  |A   |
|2  |B   |
|3  |NULL|
+---+----+

val checkNullExprs = df
.columns
.map{ c => 
    when(
        col(c).isNull, 
        raise_error(lit(s"[${c}] has null"))
    ) 
    .otherwise(col(c)).as(c)
}

df
.select(checkNullExprs:_*)
.show(false)

java.lang.RuntimeException: [ name IS NULL ]
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.RaiseError.eval(misc.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnaryExpression.eval(Expression.scala:543)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.If.eval(conditionalExpressions.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:158)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(InterpretedMutableProjection.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$47.$anonfun$applyOrElse$82(Optimizer.scala:2149)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:297)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$47.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:2149)
  at org.a

OR
df.show(false)

+----+----+
|id  |name|
+----+----+
|1   |A   |
|NULL|B   |
|3   |NULL|
+----+----+

val messageExpr = concat(
   lit("[ "), 
   concat_ws(", ", filter(array(df.columns.map(c => expr(s"""IF(COUNT(${c}) != COUNT(*), "`${c}` has nulls", NULL)""").as(c)):_*), f => f.isNotNull)), 
   lit(" ]")
).as("message")

OR

val arrayExpr = array(
    df
    .columns
    .map(c => when(
        count(col(c)) =!= count($"*"), 
        lit(s"`${c}` has nulls")
     ).as(c)):_*
)
val messageExpr = concat(
    lit("[ "), 
    concat_ws(
        ", ", 
        filter(
            arrayExpr,
            f => f.isNotNull
        )
    ), 
    lit(" ]")
).as("message")


df
.select(messageExpr)
.withColumn("message", expr("IF(LENGTH(message) > 2, RAISE_ERROR(message), CAST(NULL AS STRING))"))
.select("message")
.show(false)

java.lang.RuntimeException: [ `id` has nulls, `name` has nulls ]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.project_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)


Need help in converting this expression to simple if statement expr(s"""IF(COUNT(${c}) != COUNT(*), "${c} has nulls", NULL)""")

using when condition, there is type mismatch error is coming
